# How to hide soft keyboard suggestion for html textarea in IOS WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am writing an app using textarea tag in iOS WKWebView. I want to hide the soft keyboard suggestion(as shown in following screenshot, the bar contains three candidate words - *"devt", developers, developer*). I have configured the HTML textarea tag to autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false", but the suggestion is still there.

Is there anything else I need to do to hide the suggestion area? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" >
  How to turn off IOS keyboard suggestions?
</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: textarea with suggestion]

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue ? i am facing similar issue for iOS 15.

Comment: @SumeetGohil not yet..